# How to pass set values as a object?

Tags: python, object, set

number is a variable defined as follows in the code:

```
number=[(1, 0.44383160070768396), (1, 0.5999405754368163), (1, 0.44564960553183486)]
```

I have a method that accept object and do some operation.

```
foo = FooClass (number)
foo.method_1() #calling from FooClass
```

How I can pass the number variable as a object in python ? 
Another issue what is the difference between bind data in a variable or bind data as a object.

Any simple example will be greatly appreciate. Thanks.

Comment: `number` itself is an object only.

Comment: From your snippet, number is a list and its an object, if you need more methods or attributes then a list provides, then you can write a new class and made that number as an attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Your `number` appears to be a `list` of 2-`tuple`s. You can store this in `FooClass` as an instance attribute when you create the instance, then access it within the instance methods via `self`:

```
class FooClass(object):

    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = number

    def method_1(self):
        # use self.number here
```

There is no difference between binding data as a variable or object; in Python, everything is an object and variables are name references to these objects.

Answer (score 0):

`number=[(1, 0.44383160070768396), (1, 0.5999405754368163), (1, 0.44564960553183486)]`
<=>
`number=list((1, 0.44383160070768396), (1, 0.5999405754368163), (1, 0.44564960553183486))`

Here `number` is an object of class `list`.
And it has all the methods of this class.

now you want to have a Number class which must have its own methods:

```
class Number(list):  # <- we declare new class with list as a parent
    def method_1(self):  # <- declare method, self is keyword for instance of class
        print 'for example, ', self[0]  # <- do something
```

now we will use Number:
`number=Number((1, 0.44383160070768396), (1, 0.5999405754368163), (1, 0.44564960553183486))`

now number has class of Number, and it can do everything that list can and also have method_1:

`number.method_1()`

will print `for example, (1, 0.44383160070768396)`

try to read about subclassing